# How to refresh GridView with database when it is bound data using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am using `GridView` and have bound to SQL in the frontend using asp.net. Before button_Click  I make sure that the values of the my database table which is bound to `GridView` is reset, but it is not reflecting in the `GridView` after button_Click.

Here is my asp code for `GridView` :

```
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Profiles" HeaderText="Profiles" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="Profiles" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Location_Profile" HeaderText="Location_Profile" SortExpression="Location_Profile" />
</Columns>
```

The datasource asp code is:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TouchPadConnectionString %>"
        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Loc_Pro_Grid] ([Profiles], [Location_Profile]) VALUES (@Profiles, @Location_Profile)"
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Loc_Pro_Grid]" 
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE Loc_Pro_Grid SET Location_Profile = @Location_Profile WHERE (Profiles = @Profiles)">
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Profiles" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Location_Profile" Type="Int32" />
    </InsertParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Location_Profile" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Profiles" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

My .cs code is:

```
 protected void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

// I am doing some operations here then I am resetting the table as below

com = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Loc_Pro_Grid SET Location_Profile = 0 WHERE Profiles='" + ListBox1.Items[i].ToString() + "' ", con);
}
                    con.Open();
                    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

call `grdFoo.DataBind()` on your `button_Click` Event.

```
protected void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // I am doing some operations here then I am resetting the table as below
      com = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Loc_Pro_Grid SET Location_Profile = 0 WHERE Profiles='" +        ListBox1.Items[i].ToString() + "' ", con);
      con.Open();
      com.ExecuteNonQuery();
      con.Close();   
      // Call DataGrid's bind method here..for example
      grdFoo.DataBind()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the GridView's DataBind method to refresh the grid.

Answer (score 0):

You should refresh & bind data again as shown by **Mayak** or you can use update panel, Update data & bind `gridview` again.